# VisualForce Page not Showing up in SalesForce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I am trying to get a VisualForce Page to show up on the Salesforce1 app. I have created a brand new developer org and add 1 single page and checked the box "Available for Salesforce mobile apps"

Do i need to add something to the apex:page as well? Is there permissions on my phone or somewhere else in SF that i need to add a permission?

I have even tried just displaying this and nothing...

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <h1>
        Sample
    </h1>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1/units/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1_nav_menu Please follow above posted link ,you will get to know how to Enable vf page for salesforce1 Mobile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marking the page as 'Available for Salesforce Mobile Apps' is step one in getting a Visualforce page to show up in Salesforce1. However, you still need a way of exposing the page. There are a couple different ways of doing this:

1. A Visualforce tab
2. A Visualforce publisher action
3. Linked as a Mobile card in the enhanced page layout editor
4. By overriding a standard button, or creating a custom button or link
5. Embedding the visualforce on a record detail page layout.

If you have not exposed the visualforce page in any of the above manners, it will not display even if 'Available for Salesforce Mobile Apps' is checked.

You can check out this [handy documentation](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/winter14/release-notes/customize_sf1_visualforce.htm) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for sending over that documentation, I am VERY new to Sales Force and appreciate the pointer! Cheers!